# Can we change the appearance of the site

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I see a few sites that are in meta or live that have their own custom and tailored look.  Since this is a creative community I was wondering if we would be allowed to customize or re-design our site to be more appealing and creative in nature.  How are other boards allowed to be different?

Answer (score 3):

The custom skinning of the site comes with the graduation from beta. So unless there is an exception (if, for example, we implement the "Logo of the Week" idea), we are stuck with the Beta default looks until we go live.

But when this happens, I'm sure we will have some input :)

Comment: Wasn't there a post a while ago... here it is, from Sept 2012 http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/404/plan-for-graphic-design-design-and-promotion saying *"Graphic Design.SE has been bumped up to get a design completed ASAP... GD.SE will have a distinct look just like a graduated site... **This will, ideally, make the site look infinitely more legit,**  similar to what was done with UX's early design launch"*. As I understand it, some sites get a design before graduation, UX.SE was one such example, and apparently we were to be one too. Has the plan changed?

Comment: @user568458 I think most of Brett's ideas were sort of abandoned or postponed when he left. This was one of them. I will ask to see what happened to it and report back.

Comment: @Yisela Oh hey. Now that you mention it, I recall talk of this. To be honest, I don't know what the status of that is... my best guess at the moment is that no actual work on that happened (we have one designer and he's pretty overworked right now), but I will check tomorrow and see what's what.

Comment: @AnnaLear Thanks! There was also something else being discussed: [The possibility of having a "logo of the week/month" contest](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/581/logo-of-the-week-contest). Since we are designers, we thought it would be a good idea (like Photography does with the Photo of the week). Just opened a new question for it. We haven't discussed it properly yet because we'd need to know if it could be implemented first.